# How to get events which can be postponed for a given date from a table with change log and a table for event in Django?

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I am stuck in a scenario where I am making an API that returns events in the given a month and year combination.

The Database structure:

`Event` - has basic details of an event.
`EventLog` - has a foreignkey to the `event`, a from_date and a `to_date`.

When Events are created, an entry is made to both Event table and EventLog table (with from_date set as null).

When an Event is postponed an entry is made to EventLog with previous date and current date.

Now given a date I want to show events occurring on that date as well as the postponed events with latest dates that were supposed to happen on that day.

How should I go about it without making too many calls to the database ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the point of EventLog is to track changes to the event's starting and ending dates over time, what you should do is always store the current date in the Event table and make a note of the change in EventLog.

When an event is postponed, the date is changed in Event and also noted in EventLog.

Then your query looks like this:

```
current_events = Event.objects.filter(from_date__lte=now, to_date__gte=now)
postponed_events = Event.objects.exclude(from_date__lte=now, to_date__gte=now).filter(logs__from_date__lte=now, logs__to_date__gte=now)
all_events = current_events + postponed_events
```

And in your Event model:

```
class Event(models.Model):
    ...
    from_date = ...
    to_date = ...

    def postpone(self, from_date, to_date):
        EventLog.objects.create(event=self, from_date=self.from_date, to_date=self.to_date)
        self.from_date = from_date
        self.to_date = to_date
        self.save()
```

I know it seems like you are duplicating data by storing the from_date and to_date twice but you really aren't, especially if you only use EventLog to store changes and not the current times.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I got away by annotating max to_date and max from_date for EventLog for each event.  in short kind of group by event, with max form_date and max to_date with other event details.

Comment: Will max from_date and max to_date always be the correct dates though?

Answer (score 0):

If there is no other use of `EventLog` table, just put entries in `Entries` table and put a date of execution in that. If the date is postponed , update the date of execution in `Event` table itself.

This also assumes that you dont need the previous dates( as your requirement says that you just need to show the events happening on that day)

Comment: I need to track changes in dates for events. So have to log.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this and you can get all the events in a single query.

```
EventLog.objects.filter((Q(from_date=None) & Q(event__date=mydate)) | Q(from_date=mydate)).select_related('event')
```

Comment: How do I get the latest date for the event ? The event could have been postponed multiple times.

Comment: So the EventLog have multiple entries against each Event?

Comment: Yea, everytime, it is postponed